# Как собрать и зарегистрировать драйвер? А далее запустить и просмотреть его работу

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, драйвер

```
    // TestDriver.c

#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);
VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);

#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, UnloadRoutine)

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
  DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadRoutine;

  DbgPrint(«Hello world!\n»);

  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
  DbgPrint(«Goodbye!\n»);
}
```

wdk 8, 8.1, 10 установлены.

Какой проект надо создать в VS2015 чтобы система собрала драйвер? Я так понимаю расширение драйвера должен быть .sys? И как запустить его и проверить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Драйвер не запускают, а загружают. По сборке, думаю, должна быть информация там, откуда вы взяли этот пример.

Comment: да, спасибо. все запустил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки драйвера надо скачать WDK 7600.16385.1, далее найти x86 Checked Build Environment, написать build и у нас будет готовый драйвер.